# Remove menu on right click in Action Script 2.0

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

How can I disable menu on right click in action script 2.0 or just hide zooming from menu?

Answer (score 0):

Setting `Stage.showMenu = false` show help. It will keep only settings and about in the right click menu. Adobe documentation: http://help.adobe.com/cs_CZ/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001545.html